# SRAM force rear shifts go in the wrong direction when on largest cassette

Tags: gears, sram, shifting

I got a new bike about 6 months ago with SRAM Force on it.  It's my first time riding SRAM and I love it except for one thing:

If I'm climbing and my RD is shifted all the way up ( to 28-tooth ) and I try and downshift further, it allows me to click once and stops the 2nd click so I get an upshift instead.

Anyone know how to fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your rear derailleur is in the 28t cog, there is only one click available, because shifting to the next (non-existent) cog would put your chain in your wheel.

Because of the way the Double Tap levers work, the first click will release to the next gear down, either 27t or 26t depending on your cassette.

There is nothing to fix. This is proper behavior for this group set.

Comment: I want to down-vote you for not liking your answer, but thanks :)

Comment: Wow, that seems poorly designed. When you're hauling yourself up a mountain you're expected to know you're on the top cog and not try to grab another?

Comment: It's one of the reasons why I don't ride SRAM. I just couldn't get used to the dual nature of the lever.

Comment: I've been riding SRAM for a few years now and I positively love double-tap. It does take a little getting used to, but only a little. The difference between the single click and double is pretty large; you'd have to have some serious neuropathy in your hands to not notice it. You generally only make the accidental-upshift-while-climbing mistake once before learning the lesson. Of course, if you have a firmly-established bad habit of trying to shift into non-existent gears despite ample evidence to the contrary, it may take more :-)

Answer (score 0):

I have SRAM Force on my road bike. If I attempt to downshift, and am in my largest cog, the first click will upshift as expected. But if I press in farther, as if attempting to engage a downshift, it will cancel the upshift but resist pushing the lever further, resulting in no shift.

It's the exact analogue of trying to upshift the front derailleur when already in the highest gear. If your shifters don't work like this... I'm not sure what to say. Take it to a mechanic?